# How do i know if my project bitcode ready?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7

How do i know if my project is bitcode ready? if bitcode flag is set in project settings to YES. should i get any warnings or errors? What happen if one of my framework is not bitcode ready, will my project be a bitcode ready?

Comment: "What happen if one of my framework is not bitcode ready, will my project be a bitcode ready?" No, in case you are using external frameworks which are not bitcode ready, your project won't compile if you have bitcode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get any warnings or errors with Bitcode enabled then Yes your app will be Bitcode ready.
However if you of get warnings or errors regarding Bitcode then No it isn't.